Is there a (Neo)Vim option to use double asterisk (recursive directory search) in path for specific file types only?
I am searching for a way in Neovim to set a path recursively with ** but only for specific filetype. E.g. vim.opt.path="/a/**/*hpp" doesn't work. I want to find specific filetypes while keeping the performance of path processes in Neovim high. My current way of managing the performance of path processes is by using the vim.opt.path and vim.opt.wildignore settings and avoiding recursive search of large directories. So it looks like:
local init_path = {
        ".",
        "/a/**",
        "/b/**",
        "/usr/include/**",
        "**"
}

vim.opt.path:append(init_path)

vim.opt.wildignore = {
    '*/c/*',
    '*/d/*',
    '*.exe',
    '*.bin',
}


The whole point of the path option is to simplify searching for files by doing the search in a number of predefined directories. With a carefully defined path, you don't have to use whole paths in your includes, for example, or to be too specific with :find.
The value of path is therefore supposed to be a curated list of interesting directories, not a landfill… which makes using ,** in path an anti-pattern. ,dir/** may be acceptable in some contexts, if there is not too much depth. YMMV.
Instead of:
.,/a/**,/b/**,/usr/include/**,**

do:
.,,/a/cooldir,/b/supercooldir,/usr/include

The more specific you are, the more useful and fast file searching .
Second… applying settings to specific filetypes can be done in two ways.

With autocommands in your vimrc:
augroup MyFileTypeSettings
    autocmd FileType foo setlocal path=.,/a/cool,/b/supercool,/usr/include
augroup END

PROs:

starts simple
all in your vimrc

CONs:

verbose
quickly becomes messy
needlessly recreates existing "ftplugin" mechanism
adds redundant autocommands

Not recommended.

In dedicated filetype plugins:

Make sure you have either of the following lines in your vimrc:
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on
filetype indent plugin on


Create the ftplugin (here for the cpp filetype):
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim


Put your settings in that file:
setlocal path=.,/a/cool,/b/supercool,/usr/include



From now on, path will be locally set to the desired value whenever you edit a file with the cpp filetype.
PROs:

idiomatic
lightweight
not verbose
well organized

CONs:

many files




Maybe I misunderstood you, but that is unfortunately not what I am looking for.  I have optimized my path option pretty good from my pov. I want to optimize it further by only finding files with certain filetypes in certain dirs. Placing ** at the end first checks the previous defined directories in the path. If this is not successful, it checks all subdirs of the current working directory.

Hmm… looks like I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to define path in a filetype-specific way. Anyway, path is only about directories, not files. If you want to specifically add directories that contain a given filetype to path (is that what you are after?), then you will have to probe the desired directories yourself in a custom function and set path accordingly. See :help file-functions for a list of filesystem-related functions.

I am gonna try this. Thanks though.
